# babel-loaderの設定でexclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/しているのは何故でしょうか

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

webpackでES6構文を用いたJavascriptのコードを処理するためにbabel-loaderを利用しています。

[Github babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)にあるREADME.mdの通りに設定し、問題なく動いていることを確認できていますが、下記の設定のうち、`exclude`を指定する必要が何故あるのかがわかりません。

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

感覚的には、`node_module`内に置かれているJavascriptのコードもJavascriptで書かれているのだから、`exclude`を指定しなくても問題がないように思うのですが、この設定がないと正常に動作しないのは、何故なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論から言いますと、トランスパイルするサードパーティのpolyfillやモジュールよっては実行時にエラーになる可能性のあるものがあるからです。

こちらのQiitaの記事が参考になります
[webpackでbabel際はnode_modulesをexcludeし忘れるべからず](http://qiita.com/haribote/items/73ede4fcdf9c942f1c4f)

また、同じ作者の方が`exclude`を忘れた際にエラーがでるケースを再現したアプリケーションを公開してくれています。詳しく知りたければこちらも参考になるかと思われます。
https://github.com/haribote/do-not-miss-excluding-node-modules

Comment: 手元で実際に動かしてみました。
大変わかりやすく丁寧にありがとうございました。
レスが遅れて申し訳ありません。